# Apache : Point all Subdomain to the Main Domain

Tags: apache, redirect, subdomain

I'm sorry if this sounds stupid, I don't have the answer at all.

I was looking for a way to point all my **subdomain** (and all the future ones I'll create) to the **main domain** in Apache.

I was looking in the conf file for something like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain/public
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to allow every url possible like `salmon.domain.com` or `iamtheone.domain.com` I was wondering if in fact it was possible and how should I change my /etc/hosts file too?

**Explaination** : I want visitors of my page to think they have their own url (example if the company dell is looking my website, I would like to "give" them the URL *dell.domain.com*) I was looking for a fast way to do this, without any dns or virtualhost configuration for each ones and without redirection, only listenning every url pointing to my website...

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried with the above conf file?

Comment: Yes and it's not working ... that's why I'm posting... Did I make something wrong?